# How to run a program in another screen session?

Tags: linux, bash, command-line, gnu-screen

I want to run a program in another screen session.

Let's say I start screen like this

```
screen -S asti
```

And then I want to create a new window in that session. It's easy enough:

```
screen -S "asti" -X "screen"
```

That creates two windows in that session.

How do I run a program in that screen session?

I tried:

```
screen -S "asti" program
```

Didnt work

I  tried the -p flag... and many other attempts were made but I didnt manage to do it.

Can someone please help me?

Thanks in advance for your help and kind concern.

Comment: Give that inner screen a name and target it (with `-S`) directly? Use `-X` and "push" the escaped escape sequence for the command you want to run?

Comment: isnt it's name "asti" already? And what do you mean "push the scape sequence"? I don't know how to do it.

Comment: The external screen is named "asti". Not the internal screen. Forget the escape sequence bit for now.

Comment: Oh, you don't actually mean a second screen session. You mean that second window.

Comment: What distro are you using?

Comment: i mean any window in the screen session called "asti". I just want to execute a program there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to start a new window in an existing screen session running a specific command then you want to use

```
screen -S asti -X screen 'command'
```

To enter text into an existing screen window you need to use the `stuff` screen command to "type" into the screen window.

```
screen -S asti -p # -X stuff $'text to enter\n'
```